# How to set the StreamingContext for DataContractSerializer?

Tags: .net, datacontractserializer

I have some code something like this:

```
[DataContract]
class Foo {
    [OnSerializing]
    private void BeforeSerialize(StreamingContext ctx)
    {
        ((MtType)ctx.Context).DoStuff()
    }

    ...
}

var reader = new XmlTextReader(filename);
var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Type));
Type type = (Type)serializer.ReadObject(reader);
```

and I need to provide the `StreamingContext` structure. I have found [several references](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxremoting/thread/1db51319-9b1d-4ef1-8cff-1e7813d8a936/) that this can be done for `NetDataContractSerializer` but none for `DataContractSerializer`.

- Is there a way to make this work?
- Am I just doing this wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The use of IDataContractSurrogate lets you do custom JSON serialization and deserialization on a per-type or per-object basis.

See [IDataContractSurrogate Methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.idatacontractsurrogate_methods.aspx) for the API docs and see [DataContract Surrogate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for the sample.

Also, to read and interpret JSON, you would start with JsonReaderWriterFactory, not an XML factory. See [JsonReaderWriterFactory Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.jsonreaderwriterfactory.aspx) to see what I mean.

Hope this helps!