# How to pass StreamingContext to DataContractSerializer?

Tags: c#, serialization, datacontractserializer

I'm trying to pass some data to the StreamingContext of the DataContractSerializer, but I can't figure out how.
Here is a small sample of my code:

```
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();
DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(OldClass));
serializer.WriteObject(stream, _OldClass);
stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(NewClass));
    //here I would like to give the serializer e.g. a string as StreamingContext.Context
_NewClass = (NewClass)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
```

Comment: It seems that this is not possible. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687088/how-to-set-the-streamingcontext-for-datacontractserializer and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6928380/how-can-i-set-the-streamingcontext-in-silverlight-datacontractserizer

Answer (score 6):

You can't.

When using `DataContractSerializer`, `StreamingContext` instance, that is being passed to serialization/deserialization callbacks, comes from internal `XmlObjectSerializerContext`.

Here's initialization code:

```
internal XmlObjectSerializerContext(DataContractSerializer serializer, DataContract rootTypeDataContract, DataContractResolver dataContractResolver)  
    : this(serializer, serializer.MaxItemsInObjectGraph, new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All), serializer.IgnoreExtensionDataObject, dataContractResolver)
{
    // ...
}
```

As you can see, this code creates `new StreamingContext(StreamingContextStates.All)`.
Just for clarity, similar code for `NetDataContractSerializer` uses context, that comes from passed serializer instance:

```
internal XmlObjectSerializerContext(NetDataContractSerializer serializer) 
    : this(serializer, serializer.MaxItemsInObjectGraph, serializer.Context, serializer.IgnoreExtensionDataObject)
{
}
```

Comment: Reference source [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/XmlObjectSerializerContext.cs,e795a6c172a1c403,references) and [here](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Runtime.Serialization/System/Runtime/Serialization/DataContractSerializer.cs,5b4be2ac4b9d82e8,references), I believe.